# Алгоритм сложности O(n),язык по java

Tags: java, алгоритм

У меня есть некий файл CSV,откуда я построчно читаю данные(в файле каждая строка из себя представляет объект класса продукт) и кладу в уже специально реализованную коллекцию,которая сама сортирует продукты по цене и также есть установленное максимальное количество элементов в коллекции.Задача такая,нужно найти некое число самых низких по цене продуктов.Я правильно понимаю что алгоритм сложности здесь O(n) где n это количество строк(то есть продуктов) в файле??Я могу считать чтение и добавление  одним шагом в этом алгоритме?и в конце получить уже коллекцию самых низких продуктов каким количеством нужно.На самом деле нужно написать алгоритм поиска чтобы сложность была O(n*log(m)) где n это количество продуктов в файле,а m это количество продуктов с минимальной ценой.Я не могу понять как реализовать алгоритм который бы соответствовал этой сложности,то есть нужно реализовать так что например если в файле миллион  продуктов а нам нужно самые низкие по цене 32 продукта было O(n*5) а если нужно самые низкие по цене 64 продукта было O(n*6).В итоге чтобы сложность зависела от конкретного числа нужных продуктов низких по цене

Comment: Очень буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Добавляем все продукты в массив, сортируем по цене, а дальше если нужно взять 32 минимальных продукта, то берём саблист c индексами [0; 32) за константу, нет? Выходит максимум O(n log n) на сортировку

Comment: Заводите сортированный массив длины `m`. Построчно читаете свой файл (`O(n)`), Вставляете прочитанное значение в массив с сохранением сортировки (`O(m)`), элемент, вышедший за длину массива, удаляете. Получаем сложность `O(n)*O(log(m) = O(n*log(m))`, как и требовалось.

Comment: @Yaant делаем `n` шагов, на каждом `O(m)`, а в результате - сложность `O(n*log(m))`. Не сходится

Comment: @RomanKonoval Упс, это у меня опечатка, должно было быть `O(log(m))`. Поиск в сортированном массиве - это ж логарифм.

Comment: @IR42, ну так O(n\*lb(n)) > O(n\*lb(m)). Если я возьму n=10**8, m=100, то второй вариант уложится в несколько секунд, а первый - маловероятно. Впрочем, при таких количествах надо и с классами аккуратнее быть. Ну и ещё первый вариант жрёт больше памяти. Во втором можно использовать пул из m+1 объекта.

Comment: @Yaant, вставка в массив линейная, а не за логарифм. Это будет O(n*m).

Comment: @Qwertiy Подозреваю, что это зависит от внутренней реализации массива. Сдается мне, что можно извернуться и за константу.

Comment: @Yaant сложность вставки в отсортированный массив - `O(m)`. Поиск места вставки - `O(log(m))`, а вставка потребует копирования порядка m элементов.

Comment: @Yaant, если ты говоришь "массив", то его реализация вполне конкретна - набор последовательно расположенных в непрерывном куске памяти значений. Вот если бы ты сказал "коллекция", было бы универсальнее и зависело бы от реализации; но в тоже время без уточнения коллекции не слишком полезно. Из коллекций со вставкой за логарифм есть несколько видов деревьев (красно-чёрное и ещё несколько способов балансировки) - скорее всего что-то из них в джаве называется TreeSet и декартово дерево, которое только писать самому (у него из особенностей чтение по индексу (не по ключу) за логарифм).

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну да, слово "массив" тут было применено несколько условно, потому что я не знаю, какие именно структуры данных есть в джаве. Под массивом подразумевалась некая структура, с сортировкой и вставкой быстрее линейной. :)

Comment: я использую например реализацию TreeSet переопределяю метод add так ,чтобы после добавления удалялся последний элемент,если количество превышает заданного при создании лимита,так ка элемент может добавится где угодно в коллекции ,операция проверки на удаление каждый раз обязательна.Так вот в конце получаю отсортированную коллекцию с нужным мне количеством элементов,какая тут сложность? n -это количество строк(продуктов) в файле,m-это количество нужных мне элементов с низкой ценой

Comment: @DavitPetrosyan, я тебе уже давно в ответе про это написал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может я что-то неправильно понял, но для этого есть комментарии, в которых можно уточнить... Я бы решил примерно так. 
если вы знаете , какое количество продуктов вам нужно получить и вычитываете пообъектно данные, то вам не надо хранить все и тем более сортировать накопленные объекты (их может быть довольно много). вам достаточно иметь в памяти то количество элементов, которое требуется от вас, например 5 с минимальной ценой. тогда каждый последующий полученный из файла продукт можно сравнивать с продуктом с максимальной ценой в множестве и подменить его, если необходимо. это должно работать достаточно быстро, потому как множества не ищут перебором, а по хешу, кроме того, размер вашего множества никогда не будет превышать размер, равный необходимому вам количеству элементов. это одновременно значит, что вы фактически не зависите от объема данных, которые находятся в исходном списке. вам нужно просто читать построчно (пообъектно) и обрабатывать каждый объект, не накапливая ничего лишнего в памяти. 
реализация такова. есть интерфейс, имплементирующий компаратор для сравнения цены и абстрактный метод, возвращающий цену. наш класс, обрабатывающий данные, будет работать с наследниками этого интерфейса (так правильнее с точки зрения ооп)

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Pricable extends Comparable<Pricable>{

    Long getPrice();

    @Override
    public default int compareTo(Pricable p) {
        return this.getPrice().compareTo(p.getPrice());
    }

}

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class PriceFounder <T extends Pricable>{

    private final int capacity;

    private final TreeSet<T> set;

    public PriceFounder(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());        
    }

    public void add (T element) {
        if (set.size()<capacity) set.add(element);        
        else if (set.last().getPrice()>element.getPrice()) {
            set.remove(set.last());
            set.add(element);
        }
    }

    public Set<T> getElements(){
        return set;
    }

}
```

и теперь содаем класс для демонстрации

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //создаем тестовую коллекцию из объектов, содержащих информацию о цене
        List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Price price = new Price(Long.valueOf(r.nextInt(100)));
            prices.add(price);
            System.out.println(price);
        }

        System.out.println("***********************************************");

        //эмулируем пообъектное чтение из файла: при чтении каждого объекта вызываем метод add у объекта PriceFounder
        PriceFounder priceFounder = new PriceFounder(5);
        for (Price price : prices) {
            priceFounder.add(price);
        }

        //смотри мрезультат
        System.out.println(priceFounder.getElements());

    }

    @lombok.Data
    @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
    private static class Price implements Pricable {

        private Long price;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Может я что-то неправильно понял, но для этого есть комментарии`: если вопрос непонятен, то нужно его уточнять в комментариях к вопросу.

Comment: @ Roman Konoval спасибо, я запишу

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо большое,насчет реализации думаю проблем не будет ,я сам именно так и думал реализовать,немного по другому.Вопрос в другом,такая реализация имеет сложность O(n\*log(m))????на самом деле в приведенном пример я не понимаю как количество нам нужных элементов влияет на сложность(а в задаче судя по O(n\*log(m))   так и говорится),если есть файл с миллионом строк нам в первом случае нужно 4 самых низких по цене продукта во втором 1000 самых низких по цене продукта

Comment: в обоих случаях нам придется проверять на каждом шагу есть ли место в коллекции данному обьекту и по какому алгоритму будет происходить проверка на  вставку?

Comment: @Davit Petrosyan ваша сложность не зависит от количества элементов, она зависит от того, сколько именно нужно выбрать (например, 4). алгоритм сложности давно описан для стандартных коллекций, в т.ч. для treeset

Comment: говоря  количество нужных элементов ,я имею ввиду тоже самое что вы,то есть столько нужно выбрать из всего файла,но весь файл пройти обязательно,так как самую низкую цену может иметь самый последний элемент в  файле.O(n*) с этой частью проблем нет,я понимаю,но вот log(m) уже затрудняюсь.Дмитрий так описанный мной алгоритм получения нужным количеством продуктов в TreeSet соответствует алгоритму O(n*log(m)) ????

Comment: Дмитрий если вставка в TreeSet с имеющимся coomparator-ом происходит в O(log(m)) время ,где m это размер TreeSet(a размер никогда не превышает m) то моя задача решена,и я могу реализовать таким методом и уверенно сказать что сложность алгоритма O(n*log(m)).Но я не уверен сложность вставки в TreeSet s Comparator-ом это O(log(m))????если можете ответить буду очень благодарен

Comment: @ Davit Petrosyan прикрепил таблицу сложности алгоритмов. она в открытом доступе на просторах интернета. смотрим javadoc и в первой строке написано, что наш treeset основан на красно-черном дереве

Answer (score 3):

> Я правильно понимаю что алгоритм сложности здесь O(n) где n это количество строк(то есть продуктов) в файле??

Неправильно. Вставка в отсортированную коллекцию (с поддержанием сортировки) не может быть O(1). Скорее всего это O(lb(k)), где k - размер коллекции. Судя по описанию в вопросе, k=n. Значит итоговая сложность O(n*lb(n)).

> нужно написать алгоритм поиска чтобы сложность была O(n*log(m))

Чтобы сделать k=m, надо просто удалять лишние элементы из коллекции.

---

Вот помесь си++ с псевдокодом:

```
multiset <item> cheap;

for (unsigned q=0; q<n; ++q)
{
  cheap.insert(read_next_item());
  if (cheap.size() > m) cheap.erase(cheap.end())
}

for (auto &x : cheap)
  cout << x << endl;
```

Скорее всего в джаве нужная коллекция называется TreeSet.

Comment: `ЕкууЫуе`? Хорошее название, звучное. :)

Comment: ах, теперь понял, что было нужно автору. В java нет аналога multimap, но можно сделать через `PriorityQueue` c  `reverseOrder` компаратором

Comment: Qwertiy  Я так и делаю,а где я отметил что вставка должна быть О(1)??????Смотрите,я построчно читаю из файла строки,строк может быть миллионы,строки это- n.Прочитав одну строку я кладу обьект в коллекцию(коллекция имеет особую реализацию,которая требует при создании указать количество максимальных элементов,а также имеет comparator и сортирует по нужному мне значению обьекта),коллекция сама заботится при добавлении проверяя количество и удаляя элемент ,в случае превышения макс.количества.

Comment: Qwertiy В итоге как будет прочитан весь файл,я получаю отсортированный и с нужным мне количеством список.Конечно спасибо  за ответ ,но я как понял вы предложили мне тот же вариант ,что я описал сначала,не дав мне конкретный ответ,он является алгоритмом сложность которой  O(n*log(m)).Еще раз повторюсь n это количество продуктов(строк) в файле,а m это количество нужных мне элементов ,m также можно считать размером коллекции,это верно

Comment: @DavitPetrosyan, и сложность этого алгоритма O(n*lb(m)), какую ты и спрашивал.

Comment: @Yaant, TreeSet в неправильной раскладке)

Comment: Qwertiy Спасибо

Comment: @DavitPetrosyan, если разобрался, то надо бы ответ принять.

Comment: Qwertiy я новичок тут,не судите строго,как это сделать?

Comment: @DavitPetrosyan, слева от ответов есть галочка. Надо выбрать один ответ, который помог больше всего и нажать на галочку слева от него. Но кажется, ты её уже нашёл :)

Answer (score 0):

В Java можно сделать через `PriorityQueue`. В комментариях вы писали, что используете `TreeSet`, но у него есть одна особенность, он не хранит элементы с одинаковыми ключами. Т.е если у двух ваших продуктов одинаковая цена, то в сете будет только один из этих элементов

```
class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    int price;

    Product(int price) { this.price = price; }

    int getPrice() { return price; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.valueOf(price); }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull Product o) { return Integer.compare(getPrice(), o.getPrice()); }
}
...
List<Product> getMinPriceProducts(int m, Iterator<Product> iterator) {
    // сортировка по уменьшению, чтобы удалять max голову
    PriorityQueue<Product> products = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        products.offer(iterator.next());
        if (products.size() > m) products.remove();
    }

    List<Product> result = new ArrayList<>(products);
    Collections.sort(result);
    return result;
}
...
```

Comment: Спасибо я знаю,что Set не хранит дубликаты,но так как в моем классе присутствует не только цена ,насчет этого я могу не волноваться.Класс продукт содержит еще 4 свойства